# Neo4j: Create nodes via CYPHER/REST slow

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I try to create/update nodes via the REST API with Cypher's `MERGE`-statement. Each node has attributes of ca. 1kb (sum of all sizes). I create/update 1 node per request. (I know there are other ways to create lots of nodes in a batch, but this is not the question here.)

I use Neo4j community 2.1.6 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (24 CPUs, 64GB) and the database directory resides on a SAN drive. I get a rate of 4 - 6 nodes per second. Or in other words, a single create or update takes around 200ms. This seems rather slow for me.

The query looks like this:

```
MERGE (a:TYP1 { name: {name}, version: {version} }) 
SET 
    a.ATTR1={param1},
    a.ATTR2={param2},
    a.ATTR3={param3},
    a.ATTR4={param4},
    a.ATTR5={param5} 
return id(a)
```

There is an index on name, version and two of the attributes.

Why does it take so long? And what can I try to improve the situation?

I could imagine that one problem is that every request must create a new connection? Is there a way to keep the http connection open for multiple requests?

Comment: Have you tried passing the parameters as a map instead of individually like this? You can use the SET a += {map} syntax as a drop-in alternative to the above.

Comment: Another thought - have you tested executing this in the console to isolate the database speed from any networking or serialization effects?

Comment: I tested it remote and locally with the browser. There is no difference. I read something about a neo4j-shell, but did not found it (my Neo4j bin directory contains only a jar file, a properties and a vmoptions file and the neo4j-community.exe file). But any Cypher query in the browser takes at least about 200ms, that is even slower than the Java code with Cypher.

Comment: For Neo4j in Windows: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/11/29/neo4j-the-case-of-windows-neo4j-desktop-and-the-invisible-text/

Comment: Also could you share a profile output of your query? (prefix with `profile`) Either with Neo4j-shell or with: http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/

Answer (score 1):

For a query I'm pretty sure you can only use one index per query per label, so depending on your data they index usage might not be efficient.

As far as a persistent connection, that is possible, though I think it would depend on the library you're using to connect to the REST API.  In the ruby neo4j gem we use the Faraday gem which has a NetHttpPersistent adapter.

Comment: I use Java with json-api and jersey-bundle.

Answer (score 1):

1. The index is only used when you use ONE attribute with MERGE
2. If you need to merge on both, create a compound property, index it (or better use a constraint) and merge on that compound property
3. Use ON CREATE SET otherwise you (over-)write the attributes everytime, even if you didn't actually create the node.

#### Adapted Statement

```
MERGE (a:TYP1 { name_version: {name_version} }) 
ON CREATE SET 
    a.version = {version}
    a.name = {name}  
    a.ATTR1={param1},
    a.ATTR2={param2},
    a.ATTR3={param3},
    a.ATTR4={param4},
    a.ATTR5={param5} 
return id(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can execute a batch of cypher queries from nodejs in one communication with the Neo4j.
To run it,

- get nodejs installed (if you don't have it already)
- get a token from  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer giving you access to user_groups
- run it as > node {yourFileName}.js {yourToken}

prerequisites:

```
var request=require("request") ;
var graph = require('fbgraph');
graph.setAccessToken(process.argv[2]);

function now() {
    instant = new Date();
    return instant.getHours() 
        +':'+ instant.getMinutes() 
        +':'+ instant.getSeconds()  
        +'.'+ instant.getMilliseconds();
}
```

Get facebook data:

```
graph.get('me?fields=groups,friends', function(err,res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw now() +' Could not get groups from faceBook';
    }
```

Create cypher statements

```
    var batchCypher = [];
    res.groups.data.forEach(function(group) {
        var singleCypher = {
            "statement" : "CREATE (n:group{group}) RETURN n, id(n)",
            "parameters" : { "group" : group }
        }
        batchCypher.push(singleCypher);
```

Run them one by  one

```
        var fromNow = now();
        request.post({
            uri:"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit", 
            json:{statements:singleCypher}
        }, function(err,res) { 
            if (err) {
                console.log('Could not commit '+ group.name);
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('Used '+ fromNow +' - '+ now() +' to commit '+ group.name);
            res.body.results.forEach(function(cypherRes) {
                console.log(cypherRes.data[0].row);
            });
        })
    });
```

Run them in batch

```
    var fromNow = now();
    request.post({
        uri:"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit", 
        json:{statements:batchCypher}
    }, function(err,res) { 
        if (err) {
            console.log('Could not commit the batch');
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Used '+ fromNow +' - '+ now() +' to commit the batch');
    }) 
});
```

The log shows that a transaction for 5 groups is significantly slower than a transactions for 1 group but significantly faster than 5 transactions for 1 group each.

```
Used 20:38:16.19 - 20:38:16.77 to commit Voiture occasion Belgique
Used 20:38:16.29 - 20:38:16.82 to commit  Marches & Randonnées
Used 20:38:16.31 - 20:38:16.86 to commit Vlazarus
Used 20:38:16.34 - 20:38:16.87 to commit Wijk voor de fiets
Used 20:38:16.33 - 20:38:16.91 to commit Niet de bestemming maar de route maakt de tocht goed.
Used 20:38:16.35 - 20:38:16.150 to commit the batch
```

I just read your comment, Andreas, do it is not applicable for you, but you might use it to find out if the time is spent in the communication or in the updates

Comment: I know, but my code is called for a single node update. I do not know if and when another call comes.